# Check if app is de-authorized facebook android SDK 4.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token

Trying to integrate **Facebook Android SDK 4.0** via a sample app.

Questions:

1. How can we check if the app has been de-authorized by the user in the app dashboard. Tried using the `AccessTokenTracker` in the new SDK documentation, but that doesn't seems to be getting called upon when i de-authorize the app.

The `AccessTokenTracker` is only called when i `login` or change the password on the account. Is there any other class for checking the de-authorization of an app?

The sample app: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/b384c0655fe96db71229bfdcb981a522f3f1e675/samples/Scrumptious/src/com/facebook/scrumptious/MainActivity.java

2. Where exactly is the `AccessToken` stored in our app?

The documentation on the developer.facebook is real poor as of now.
I only want to use the `SDK`. I don't intend to use the `Graph API` along with that.
Any ideas is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The SDK calls the Graph API. So of course you need to do some kind of call to Facebook which will be a Graph API call

Comment: I am initializing the facebookSDK and everything. I can do a post and all the good stuff. The only issue is i cant seem to find out if the app has been  deauthorized. EDIT: are you saying that we must use the graph API? In that case how am  i able to do a post without explicitly calling a graph API URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You won't get a call on the client when the user de-auths your app. What will happen is when you do a call, it will fail. The GraphResponse's getError will be not null. In this case, the FacebookRequestError's category is LOGIN_RECOVERABLE, as you need to take the user to the login flow again. You can call one of these methods to start that process with the response you received: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/b384c0655fe96db71229bfdcb981a522f3f1e675/facebook/src/com/facebook/login/LoginManager.java#L96-L115

2) The access token is stored in your application's shared preferences under the key com.facebook.AccessTokenManager.CachedAccessToken

Comment: your answer does help. It does lead to a question though. The getting started documentation for the SDK doesn't state anything about a graphResponse. It has a callback on a LoginManager. Are you saying that Graph API usage is required as well. Do you mind writing some pseudo-code or pointing me to some links/docs?

Comment: rather what is the callback that i am listening for here to get the LOGIN_RECOVERABLE error code?

Comment: This depends on what you want to do after you login with Facebook. Mostly you're going to call functions on the Graph API, and they will return a GraphResponse, the error will be on that GraphResponse object.  You can also use the ShareApi which internally uses the Graph API, for these, the onError callback will have a FacebookException. You'd need to check if it's of type FacebookGraphResponseException, and then that will have a GraphResponse as well.

Comment: Do you mean using FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> on the shareDialog.registerCallback? I already tried that, the onError is never called in the abstract impl

Comment: No, the share dialogs do not actually require the user to be logged in (via your app) in order to post, so even if they've de-authorized you app, they can still use the share dialog. You will only get an error if you use the ShareApi methods, or the GraphRequest (or Login again).

Comment: @MingLi - If i de-authorize the app and try to do a post, i see a share dialog which says an error has occured. I am not able to do a post. So how do i make do a login again in case the user did a de-authorization of the app. And how can i use the shareAPI? the whole documentation is utter confusing.

Comment: Alright so i got it working. I figured out the problem. I would like to point out though that i appreciate the open source project that you guys put out, but it would be great for third party devs if the documentation could be a bit better. But anyways, thanks a lot to both of you for helping me out!